# Mongoose model unit testing - Connection wont close if any test cases fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, hapi.js-lab

I'm creating some unit tests for my Mongoose models using Lab and [Mockgoose](https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose), and I'm having the DB connection opened via Labs `lab.before()` method, then the database connection killed in labs `lab.after()` method. The problem I'm running into, is if any test cases fail, then the connection won't close, but the `lab.after()` **does** get executed (I added some console output for debugging)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mockgoose = require('mockgoose')
const appRoot = require('app-root-path')

mockgoose( mongoose )

// Create the mongoose connection on init
before(function(done) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://example.com/TestingDB', function(err) {
        done(err)
    })
})

// Close the fake connection after all tests are done
after(function(done) {
    console.log('Closing') // Shows in console (always)
    mongoose.connection.close(function() {
        console.log('Closed') // Also. always shows in console
        done()
    })
})

const Models = appRoot.require('./dist/models')(mongoose)

describe('Foobar', function () {
    describe('.createFoo', function () {
        it( 'Creating foo with no data', function( done ) {

            // Executing Foobar.createFoo with an empty object WILL populate err
            Models.Foobar.createFoo( { /* Some Data.. */ }, ( err, data ) => {
                // This will fail the test case, since err will contain an error..
                expect( err ).to.not.equal( null )
                done()
            } )
        })
    })
})
```

So if I change the:

```js
expect( err ).to.not.equal( null )
```

to:

```js
expect( err ).to.equal( null )
```

Then it works perfectly fine. But if I simulate a test case failing, then both the "**Closing**" and "**Closed**" show up in the console, but the connection itself never closes... It just hangs there until I hit ctrl+c

Am I missing something in the code above?

#### Update

I looked through the running processes to see if there was a processing hanging when the test case failed:

```
$ ps aux |grep -i [m]ongo
myuser          3666   0.0  0.5  3054308  19176 s003  S+    2:27PM   0:00.08 node /Users/me/my_project/node_modules/mongodb-prebuilt/binjs/mongokiller.js 3608 3663
```

Comment: Never used 'to.not.equal' assertion for tests, I would stick 'to.equal' if it works.  Also I make and close connection after every test or create a variable that I set to null beforeEach test.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a bug in Mockgoose@5.2.4, upgrading to  5.3.3 solved this (But broke something else :( )